# Ошибки. Нужно починить код

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1)Не правильно отображаются русские символы при выводе на экран;

2)Ошибка при вводе ФИО [image: введите сюда описание изображения];

3) ЗНО-> ВНО;

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

class University
{

public:

    string identity; string name; string city; string Univer; int Specialization;

    float ZNO[3]; float avgedu; float plusmarks;

};

int main(int argv, char* argc[]) {

    setlocale(NULL, "RUS");

    int list;

    cout << "Введите объем списка "; cin >> list;

    vector<University>STUDENTS(list);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < list; i++)
    {

        getline(cin, STUDENTS[i].name);
        cout << "Фамилия и инициалы: "<<endl;
        cin>> STUDENTS[i].name;

        cout << "Идентификационный код: " << endl;
        cin>> STUDENTS[i].identity;

        cout << "Город: "<<endl;
        cin>> STUDENTS[i].city;

        cout << "Средний балл: "<<endl;
        cin >> STUDENTS[i].avgedu;

        cout << "Дополнительные баллы: "<<endl;
        cin >> STUDENTS[i].plusmarks;

        for (size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            cout << "ЗНО: "<<j+1<<" ";
            cin >> STUDENTS[i].ZNO[j];
        }

        cout << "Университет: "<<endl;
        cin>>STUDENTS[i].Univer;

        cout << "Специальность: "<<endl;
        cin>>STUDENTS[i].Specialization;

    }

    system("cls");

    for (size_t j = 0; j < list; j++)
    {

        cout << "Фамилия и инициалы: " << STUDENTS[j].name << endl;

        cout << "Идентификационный код: " << STUDENTS[j].identity << endl;

        cout << "Город: " << STUDENTS[j].city << endl;

        cout << "Средний балл: " << STUDENTS[j].avgedu << endl;

        cout << "Дополнительные баллы: " << STUDENTS[j].plusmarks << endl;

        for (size_t k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            cout << "ЗНО: " << k + 1 << " " << STUDENTS[j].ZNO[k] << endl;

        }
        cout << "Университет: " << STUDENTS[j].Univer << endl;

        cout << "Специальность: " << STUDENTS[j].Specialization << endl;


    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей". Кстати, если работаете по-русски, то не ЗНО, а ВНО :)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо проверить в какой кодировке сохранён файл с исходным кодом. Кодировка должна совпадать с той что используется в консоли. По-умолчанию в Windows c русской локалью, по крайней мере раньше, использовалась `cp866`, проверить можно введя в консоли команду `chcp`.
Либо можно использовать юникод, изменив соответствующим образом код.